# Function only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made this little jQuery function to make my navigation slide out on mobile devices.  My only problem though... I can only show and hide it once... Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

```
$('#menu-btn').click(function(){

  if ($('nav ul').css('margin') == '83px 0px 0px -225px') {

    $('nav ul').animate({
      margin:'83px 0px 0px 0px'
    }, 200);

  }
  else {

    $('nav ul').animate({
      margin:'83px 0px 0px -255px'
    }, 200);

  }

});
```

Comment: Just a little typo... `'83px 0px 0px -225px'` versus `'83px 0px 0px -255px'`

Comment: @Buggabill great. Make it an **answer**

Comment: you can improve you code and avoid such cases in future - `$('#menu-btn').click(function(){ $('nav ul').toggleClass('slided') }` and update your CSS  : `nav ul { margin: 83px 0px 0px 0px}` and nav `ul.slided { margin: 83px 0px 0px -225px}`

Comment: @codehx - #2 here says otherwise - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Otherwise, I would.  This question should be closed.  I wanted to help the user a little, but this will not help anyone in the future.

Comment: thanks @Buggabill it is indeed my answer. Stupid beginners mistake. * facepalm *

Comment: You should store that string once in a var and re-use it to avoid these kind of errors. And/or maybe use something else as a state identifier that translates to a bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative solution you can follow this way:

You may toggle class with margins on every click instead string compare

```
$('#menu-btn').click(function() {
    $('nav ul').toggleClass('slided')    
})
```

Also you need 2 CSS rules

```
nav ul {
    margin: 83px 0px 0px 0px
}

nav ul.slided {
    margin: 83px 0px 0px -225px
}
```

Comment: It will add margin but not animiate the `nav ul`.

Comment: You'd need to add css transitions as well to get the same effect. Also, transitions might not be supported in all browsers he/she has to support.

Comment: Yep, transitions may be added in case author need animation, but in original code only margins are in use.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var flag=true;
$(function(){
    $('#menu-btn').click(function(){      
        var newMargin = flag===true ? '83px 0px 0px -225px' : '83px 0px 0px 0px';
        $('nav ul').animate({
           margin: newMargin // toggle margin according to flag
        }, 200);
        flag = !flag;//toggle flag
    });
});
```

```css
nav ul {
    margin: 83px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>List 1</li>
        <li>List 2</li>
        <li>List 3</li>
        <li>List 4</li>
        <li>List 5</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<br/>
<button id="menu-btn">Click</button>
```

Try this,

```
var flag=true;

$(function() {
    $('#menu-btn').click(function() {      
        var newMargin = flag==true ? '83px 0px 0px -225px' : '83px 0px 0px 0px';

        $('nav ul').animate({
           margin: newMargin //toggle margin according to flag
        }, 200);

        flag = !flag; //toggle flag
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this -

```
$('#menu-btn').click(function(){
    if ($('nav ul').css('margin-left') == '225px') {
        $('nav ul').animate({
          margin:'83px 0px 0px 0px'
        }, 200);
    } else {
        $('nav ul').animate({
            margin:'83px 0px 0px 225px'
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

Issue with your code was that you were trying to get the shorthand property of margin, which as per jQuery's documentation, is not guaranteed to work -

> Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., margin, background, border), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed.